# Algoritmo Kamila

Tags: r, csv, algoritmos, rstudio, data

estoy tratando de aplicar el algoritmo de kamila, ya que tengo variables continuas y categóricas. En la tercer línea del código, me sale un error:

```
data<-read.csv("VARIABLES_R_KAMILA.csv", header = FALSE, sep =";")
conInd <- c(1:26)
conVars <- data[,conInd]

Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , conInd) : undefined columns selected
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a resolver, no entiendo a que se refiero dicho error?
Muchas gracias

Estoy tratando de replicar un código para el algoritmo "Kamila" en rstudio. Este es el código:

```html
data <- read.csv("binarymat.csv",header=FALSE,sep=";")
conInd <- c(9)
conVars <- data[,conInd]
conVars <- data.frame(scale(conVars))
catVarsFac <- data[,c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)]
catVarsFac[] <- lapply(catVarsFac, factor)
catVarsDum <- dummyCodeFactorDf(catVarsFac)
kamRes <- kamila(conVars, catVarsFac, numClust=5, numInit=10,
            calcNumClust = "ps",numPredStrCvRun = 10, predStrThresh = 0.5)
summary(kamRes)
```

Pero en mi caso desde la tercer línea del código me aparece error y no sé ¿por qué?

Les agradezco su apoyo

Comment: Edita por favor y agrega tu código

Comment: Lo más probable es que tu archivo csv no tenga 26 columnas. ya que con `conVars<-data[,conInd]` le estás indicando que te seleccione las primeras 26 columnas.

Comment: Efectivamente, debes tener menos columnas de las que esperas, verificalo con `ncol(data)`

Comment: Hola @césarhuamanininahuanca ya verifique y en efecto mi archivo csv tiene más columnas. Ya le he indicado el número correcto de columnas y me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Comment: Hola @BetaM, he adjuntado el código que quiero replicar. Mi script es idéntico pero la ruta del archivo es diferente. Sin embargo a partir de la tercer línea del código me sale error: Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , conInd) : undefined columns selected

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho, muchas gracias. Acabo de intentar lo que me comentas y el resultado es que solo tengo una columna: 1. Pero en el archivo csv ya lo verifique y tiene 32 columnas. No entiendo porqué me arroja ese resultado. ¿Qué puedo hacer para que lea las 32 columnas? Muchas gracias

Comment: A todos muchas gracias por su apoyo, encontré el error de mi código. Ya logré que corra. Les agradezco muchísimo por leerme, ustedes me ayudaron a encontrar el error. Apenas estoy iniciando en el mundo de la programación y cada día aprendo algo nuevo. Saludos

Comment: mira por favor el [tour]... es cribir una respuesa explicando que paso y como lo solucionaste esta muy bien visto...